# Android Studio 2.2.1: cannot resolve symbol 'wearable'

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I've create a new project wear (API 20) in Android Studio 2.2.1 in Ubuntu 14.04, yet I can't use CanvasWatchFaceService, because wearable in android.support not exist.

Help me, please.

Comment: Can you show us your build.gradle file ?

Comment: The link at the code [build.gradle](http://paste.ofcode.org/38gQwpxpmuL22TbNu2RnEjg).

Comment: Kindly check if this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892474/android-wear-gradle-dependency-issues-cannot-resolve-symbol) is related to your problem.

Comment: @noogui: I'd like building a Watch Face Service, the guide that I use is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service.html#CallbackMethods).

Comment: I noticed Grandle is malfunctioning. Grandle does not perform in sync and console there are many mistakes.